# Can't find Element Inside Template with querySelectorAll

Tags: polymer-1.0

Im done with visual things of my proj. Now, trying to put template tags. But my 'click toggle' event isnt working now. Tried lots of solutions. At the same time you may give hints about polymer.

Putted template tags like this:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isUnis(tabSelected)}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{unis}}">
        <paper-icon-item u="{{item.name}}">
            <iron-image src="{{unImg(item.name)}}" sizing="contain" style="width:32px;height:32px" item-icon fade preload></iron-image>
            <div class="flex">{{item.name}}</div>
            <span>1</span>
        </paper-icon-item>
    </template>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isDers(tabSelected)}}">
    <paper-icon-item u="İstanbul">
        <iron-image src="/unis/uni/istanbul.png" sizing="contain" style="width:32px;height:32px" item-icon fade preload></iron-image>
        <div class="flex">İstanbul</div>
        <span>1</span>
    </paper-icon-item>
</template>
```

And my script inside template:

```
var notarApp = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('notar-app');
    document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        var p = Polymer.dom(notarApp.root).querySelectorAll('paper-icon-item'),
            sifir = 0,
            buyuttu = document.getElementById('#buyuttu'),
            selected = document.getElementById('#selected');
        for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            p[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                this.classList.toggle('shadow-2');
                var listme = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
                    if (!(hasClass(p[j], 'shadow-2'))) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    listme.push(" " + p[j].attributes[0].nodeValue);
                    selected.innerHTML = listme;
                }
                if (listme.length == 0) {
                    selected.innerHTML = 'Listelemek için üniversite ve/ya ders seçin';
                }
                if (sifir == 0 && listme.length > 4) {
                    buyuttu.show();
                    sifir++;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Last i tried this inside polymer-ready and nothing happened:

```
if(p.length) {
   console.log(p);
}
```

My guess is dom-if doesnt load content when if state is false.

Comment: If i cant solve this i will try materializecss.

Comment: Working now. But i dont want like this.

Removed dom-if's and replaces polymer-ready to WebComponentsReady